# how change images size according to media query?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm trying to implement this **portfolio** in this link :

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo_show/1258

I download and implement it in my mvc5 project and it works fine,but I have some problem in css and media query used in this portfolio .I want to make some changes in size of images and number of columns when I shrink the browser . in this portfolio all images should be 144x144px in 4 columns but I don't want it . I want bigger images, also I want it worke like bootstrap grid system , but when I  shrink the browser columns changed to 1 column.can anyone help me ?
 I don't know anything about media query.

2 css files :

```css
/* CSS reset */
body,div,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
html,body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height: 100%;
}
img { 
 border:0;
}
header{
 display: block;
}
/* General Demo Style */
body{
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 background:url(images/bg.png);
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #3a2127;
}
a{
 color: #333;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#container{
 position: relative;
}
.clr{
 clear: both;
}
#container > header{
 padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
#container > header h1{
 position: relative;
 color: #275973;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-style: normal;
 font-size: 25px;
 padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
#container > header h1 strong{
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed','Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
 padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;
 line-height:35px; 
 color:#275973;
 font-size:28px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
#container > header h1 span{
 font-family: 'Alegreya SC', Georgia, serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-style: italic;
 color:#5a99ba;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
/* Buttom Style */
.freshdesignweb-top{
 text-align:center;
 color:#275973;
 line-height: 44px;
 font-size: 11px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow: 3px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.freshdesignweb-top a{
 color:#fcca00;
}
.freshdesignweb-top a:hover{
 color:#0b2f42;
}
.freshdesignweb-top h1{
 margin:0 auto;
 width:490px;
 background:url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed','Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size:36px;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #F2F2F2, 1px 2px 0px #B1B1B2;
}
/* Buttom Style */
.freshdesignweb-buttom{
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed','Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
 color:#009;
 line-height: 24px;
 font-size: 11px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow: 3px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.freshdesignweb-buttom a{
 padding: 0px 10px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #fff;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}
.freshdesignweb-buttom a:hover{
 background:#FFF;
}
.freshdesignweb-buttom span.right{
 float: right;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.freshdesignweb-buttom span.right a{
 display: block;
}
.freshdesignweb{ 
    margin:0 auto;
 width:650px;
}
```

```css
/* Portolio Hover */
.da-thumbs li ,
.da-thumbs li  img {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
.da-thumbs li  {
 overflow: hidden;
}
.da-thumbs li  article {
 position: absolute;
 background-image:url(images/image_hover.png);
 background-repeat:repeat;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.da-thumbs li  article.da-animate {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
/* Initial state classes: */
.da-slideFromTop {
 left: 0px;
 top: -100%;
}
.da-slideFromBottom {
 left: 0px;
 top: 100%;
}
.da-slideFromLeft {
 top: 0px; 
 left: -100%;
}
.da-slideFromRight {
 top: 0px;
 left: 100%;
}
/* Final state classes: */
.da-slideTop {
 top: 0px;
}
.da-slideLeft {
 left: 0px;
}
.da-thumbs li  article a {
 color:#fff;
 padding:20px;
 display:block;
}

.da-thumbs {
text-align:center;
}

.da-thumbs li  article h3{
color:#fff;
padding-top:30px;
}

.da-thumbs li  article em{
margin-bottom:10px;
color:#fff;
display:block;
}

.da-thumbs li  article span{
display:inline-block;
}

span.link_post{
display:block;
width:35px;
height:35px;
background-color:#DF6232;
border-radius:50px;
cursor:pointer;
background-image:url(images/link_post_icon.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
margin-right:10px;
}

span.zoom{
overflow:hidden;
display:block;
width:35px;
height:35px;
background-color:#DF6232;
border-radius:50px;
cursor:pointer;
background-image:url(images/zoom_icon.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
margin-left:10px;
}

.portfolio_2col article h3{
padding-top:70px !important;
}

/* Image Grid */
.image_grid {
 float:left;
 overflow:hidden;
 width:700px;
 position:relative;

}

.image_grid li{
 float: left;
 line-height: 17px;
 color: #686f74;
 list-style:none;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin-bottom:23px;
 margin-right:23px;
 text-align:center;
}


/* Responsive image grid*/
/* Mobile landscape width 320 */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

.image_grid{
width:300px;
}

.image_grid li img{
width:220px;
}

.portfolio_4col .da-thumbs li article h3{
padding-top:70px;
}

.portfolio_3col .da-thumbs li article h3{
padding-top:50px;
}

.portfolio_2col .da-thumbs li article h3{
padding-top:53px !important;
}

}


 @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {

.image_grid{
width:450px;
}

.image_grid li{
width:178px !important;
}

.portfolio_4col .da-thumbs li article h3{
padding-top:58px;
}

.portfolio_3col .da-thumbs li article h3{
padding-top:34px;
}

.portfolio_2col .da-thumbs li article h3{
padding-top:23px !important;
}

}
```

Comment: Yes, you can change this layout to Bootstrap. All you need to do is [read this](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).

Comment: thanks , I know these but I don't know how use it in this sample @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: what is the column number you have added ?

Comment: 4 columns , this is not my code and I don't know where specified these numbers :/ @afelixj

Comment: check this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same code and style in the example with larger image.

Delete or Change the `width` in the below style rules.

```
.freshdesignweb {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 650px;
}
.image_grid {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 700px;
  position: relative;
}
```